# How to configure (filter) logs in SoapUI project which is executed with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, logging, log4j, soapui

I have a SoapUI-Pro project that is configured and running in Jenkins. The problem is that the properties data is logged in the Jenkins console output, which is undesirable. Interestingly, the properties are only logged if the TestSuits fail.

How can I disable the output logs for properties? 
I know it could be probably configured with the log4j.xml file, but I don't know exactly how?

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is an error (not correctly implemented) in the Ready API that does not allow you to encrypt data in your projects. However, I have found a solution for my problem. I change the Jenkins job configuration to filter the output logs of the Ready API.

$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.sh -j -E $Env my-soapui-project.xml | sed -E 's/(Password:)(.*?)/\1 XXXXX/g'